# Swaping two value from spinner

Tags: android, events, button

There is a button called swap in my android application.now i want swap the  value between two spinner.
i created  spinner by doing the following:

```
fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.from_currency_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.to_currency_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
swap.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        //swap logic here
    });
```

Can anybody help to me to write the method?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it according to your above given setup:

Find the first spinner by it's view id and save its value in a temporary variable. Then do the same with a second spinner, but assign it's value to the first spinner (instead of a temporary variable) and at last assign the value of the temporary variable (which currently holds the original value of the first spinner) as the value to the second spinner.

Hope that helps.